# Prove this binomial identity using induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

prove this identity:

$(1-x)^{-k} = \sum\limits_{i>=0}  \binom {n+k-1} {k-1} x^n  $

using induction.

Verification for k=1 is trivial.
assuming k= i, proving the identity when k=i+1 is something i am having problem with.

This is what i have done:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}kx^n&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n+k-1}k\right)x^n\\
&=(1-x)^{-k}+\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}kx^n\\
&=(1-x)^{-k}+\sum_{n\ge 1}\binom{n+k-1}kx^n\\
&=(1-x)^{-k}+x\sum_{n\ge 1}\binom{n+k-1}kx^{n-1}\\
&=(1-x)^{-k}+x\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}kx^n\;.
\end{align*}$$

how do i finish the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction,

On solving for $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}kx^n\;.$$

You get that $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}kx^n\;= (1-x)^{-k-1}$$

And that is what you needed to prove. You are done:)

Answer (score 1):

You’re practically done: just solve your equation for

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}kx^n\;.$$

Comment: Please take a look at this question, its related to this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289014/how-to-find-the-coefficients-of-this-power-series