# Generating series using partitions

Tags: combinatorics

A partition of $n$ is a monotone decreasing sequence of positive integers which sum up to $n$; i.e. $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k)$ where $\lambda_1 +···+\lambda_k = n$ and $\lambda_1 ≥ \lambda_2 ≥ ··· ≥ \lambda_k > 0$. Let $P_n$ be the set of all partitions of $n$.

For example, there are seven partitions of $5$: $(5),(4,1),(3,2),(3,1,1),(2,2,1),(2,1,1,1),(1,1,1,1,1)$.

**Question 1:** For each partition $\sigma = (\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k)$, define the weight function $w(\sigma):=\lambda_1$ (i.e. the largest term). Determine the generating series $\Phi_{P_5}(x)$ of $P_5$ with respect to $w$

This is what I did:

$\Phi_{P_5} = x+x^2+x^2+x^3+x^3+x^4+x^5 = x+2x^2+2x^3+x^4+x^5$

What mistake am I making? Am I not considering the weights properly?

**Question 2:** For each partition $\sigma = (\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k)$, define the weight function $w'(\sigma) = 7\lambda_1$. Let $\Phi'_{P_n}(x)$ be the generating series for $P_n$ with respect to $w'$. Determine $\Phi'_{P_5}(x)$, and find the relationship between $\Phi_{P_n}(x)$ and $\Phi'_{P_n}(x)$ in general.

Note $w'(\sigma) = 7w(\sigma)$; using this I can find $\Phi'_{P_5}(x)$, but I am unable to find the relationship between $\Phi_{P_n}(x)$ and $\Phi'_{P_n}(x)$.

Please help, I am new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you copy and paste all of those symbols? It is MUCH faster to just pick up a few measly $\LaTeX$ commands so you can type those in, like $\Phi$ or $x^2$. Look at the documentation of MathJax (or a variety of sites with quick tutorials online).

Comment: @jm324354 i made the required edits.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the first question looks fine to me. For the second, note that a partition of $n$ that contributes to the $x^k$ term of $\Phi_{P_n}(x)$ (i.e., that has $w$-weight $k$) must have $w'$-weight $7k$ and therefore contribute to the $x^{7k}=(x^7)^k$ term of $\Phi_{P_n}'(x)$. Thus, if

$$\Phi_{P_n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\;,$$

then

$$\Phi_{P_n}'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^{7k}=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(x^7)^k=\Phi_{P_n}(x^7)\;.$$

(It’s clear that $n$ has a single partition of weight $n$ and no partition of greater weight, so the first summation really does have an upper limit of $n$.)